# Access local variable from outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I'm using [TopUp](http://gettopup.com/) to make a simple slideshow. Unfortunately they don't expose the image index.

Is there a way I can access the local variable "index" without having to modify the original script?

```
TopUp = (function() {
 var index = null;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nope. That's how they do _truly_ private variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying the original script, you can't.

But if you just want to be able to read the value of `index`, the modification could be really simple, by adding a little function in the objet returned :

```
getIndex : function() {
  return index;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get that variable out. Looking at the (somewhat scary) source, It doesn't look like the "ondisplay" callback is passed anything useful, but it's not really clear (and the documentation doesn't mention the parameters at all).