# Uncaught ReferenceError: $(Petlist which i think i have defined?) is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting this error code saying 'Petlist' is undefined yet I defined it earlier as a blank string. How do I fix this error message? I want this program to eventually put all the user input together into a string to be returned.  I want to add an error code if someone forgets to type something in, so they will be prompted to fill in the text.

```js
var $ = function (id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var processInfo = function ()
{
    //Setting varibles from HTML
    var first = $('firstname');
    var last = $('lastname');
    var petnum = $('numpets');

    //For loop for pet names
    var Petlist = "";
    for (cntr = 1; cntr <= petnum.value; cntr++)
    {
    petID = 'pet' + cntr;
    PetName = $(petID).value + ' ';
    Petlist += PetName;
    }

    //Checking for blank strings to be filled
    var ef = $('firstname').length;
    var el = $('lastname').length;
    var ep = $('numpets').length;
    var errmsgfirst = '';
    var errmsglast = '';
    var errmsgpet = '';
    if (parseInt(ef) === 0)
    {
        errmsgfirst = 'Please enter your first name. ';
    } else{
        errmsgfirst = '';
    }
    if (parseInt(el) === 0)
    {
        errormsglast = 'Please enter your last name. ';
    } else{
        errmsglast = ''
    }
    if (parseInt(ep) === 0)
    {
        errormsgpet = 'Please enter the number of pets';
    } else{
        errormsgpet = ''
    }


}

$("msg").innerHTML = Petlist;
$("errormsgfirst").innerHTML = errmsgfirst;
$("errormsglast").innerHTML = errmsglast;
$("errormsgpet").innerHTML = errmsgpet;

window.onload = function ()
{
$("mybutton").onclick = processInfo;
}
```

```css
body 
 {
 background-color: silver;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 }
 span {
 color: red;
 }
 #message {
 color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color: silver">
<h1>Assignment 2</h1>
<p>Enter First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname"> <span id="firstname_error"></span></p>
<p>Enter Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname"> <span id="lastname_error"></span>
</p>
<p>How Many Pets do you have? (0-3): <input type="text" id="numpets" size="1" maxlength="1">
<span id="numpets_error"></span>
</p>
<p>List your Pet's names:
<input type="text" id="pet1">
<input type="text" id="pet2">
<input type="text" id="pet3">
</p>
<p><input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Submit Information"></p>
<p id="errormsgfirst"></p>
<p id="errormsglast"></p>
<p id="errormsgpet"></p>
<p id="msg"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: You only declared/defined `Petlist` inside the `processInfo` function. You can't access it outside (if you try, you get exactly this error).

Comment: Parser is correct. Re: variable scoping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access local variable from outside the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770323/access-local-variable-from-outside-the-function)